# Get text after the span with a class with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have this structure

```
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                         123                       <br>
```

I want to get "123"

this code get between the tag if exist

```
var username = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p[@class='glyphicon-user']");
//Response.Write(username.InnerText);
```

but i want to get "123"

Comment: You need to publish a bigger structure. (That includes the p paragraph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way, based solely on the HTML sinppet posted so far :

```
var query = "//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-user']/following-sibling::text()[1]";
var username = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(query);
Console.WriteLine(username.InnerText.Trim());
```

Basically the XPath looks for `span` with certain `class` attribute value, and then return the *nearest text node* located after the `span`. There might be a better way depending on your exact need and the actual HTML structure.

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/55rYG2)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
123
```

Comment: thanks, if 123 be in the <span>123</span> , how can i get it?

Comment: @nasr Where that span is located? Post more HTML for context. Please understand that we can't provide accurate suggestion given that very little piece of information (realize that only you can see the actual HTML). This is also what the comment to your question implied...

Comment: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                   <span>      123             </span>          <br>

Comment: Instead of nearest following sibling *text node*, for this case you want nearest following sibling *span element* : `//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-user']/following-sibling::span[1]`

Comment: it does not work nad eror is :: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @nasr should work, unless your HTML is not as you posted in the comment above. See the demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/AQXbYQ

Comment: @nasr Since you confirmed it worked, please accept this answer. More info : [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks